# spl-token-lending program giving error invalid program arguments on account initReserve instruction

Tags: untagged

I have created an init lending market with quote currency USD and that works fine for me but when I try to call initReserve from js library it give me invalid program argument error despite giving the correct accounts. i have used https://pyth.network/developers/accounts/?cluster=devnet to get pythproduct and pythprice pubkey for USDC. please help me with this.

There are two instructions that I followed and are mentioned below with code

1. to init the lending market

```
import {
  initLendingMarketInstruction,
  isLendingMarket,
  LENDING_MARKET_SIZE,
  LENDING_PROGRAM_ID,
  parseLendingMarket,
} from "@solana/spl-token-lending";
import {
  PublicKey,
  Connection,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Keypair,
  BPF_LOADER_DEPRECATED_PROGRAM_ID,
  Transaction,
  SystemProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { GET_OWNER, GET_PAYER } from "./ids";
import buffer from "buffer";
import { parseProductData } from "@pythnetwork/client";

async function first() {
  const owner = GET_OWNER;

  console.log("connected owner: ", owner.publicKey.toBase58());
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

  const lendingMarket = Keypair.generate();
  const quoteCurrency = buffer.Buffer.from(
    "USD\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  );

  const info = await connection.getAccountInfo(
    new PublicKey("6NpdXrQEpmDZ3jZKmM2rhdmkd3H6QAk23j2x8bkXcHKA")
  );

  const parsed = parseProductData(info!.data);
  console.log("info", parsed);

  const LendingMarketInitBalanceNeeded =
    await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(LENDING_MARKET_SIZE);

  const accounttx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: owner.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: lendingMarket.publicKey,
    lamports: LendingMarketInitBalanceNeeded,
    space: LENDING_MARKET_SIZE,
    programId: LENDING_PROGRAM_ID,
  });

  const ins = initLendingMarketInstruction(
    owner.publicKey,
    quoteCurrency,
    lendingMarket.publicKey
  );

  const transaction = new Transaction();
  transaction.add(accounttx);
  transaction.add(ins);

  const recent_blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.recentBlockhash = recent_blockhash.blockhash;
  transaction.feePayer = owner.publicKey;

  const tx = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [
    owner,
    lendingMarket,
  ]);

  console.log("hash: ", tx);
  console.log("lending market: ", lendingMarket.publicKey.toBase58());
}

first();

// lending market : A1yW5zh4p8JWMTJPGbJyh8EQj9LhnMzSWL1uFUEkhu3e
// hash : 3SVx26KpDUtZAVnomjHbJNqha9yV7wypLQQ1n5sqQgWzJjZEsmQChzufgY9ntDcZxPQ5UVNrwyNLGjDmHLry1xQz
```

2. to init the reserve

```
import {
  clusterApiUrl,
  Connection,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  PublicKey,
  Keypair,
  Transaction,
  SystemProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { GET_OWNER, GET_PAYER } from "./ids";
import * as pyth from "@pythnetwork/client";
import {
  initReserveInstruction,
  // LENDING_PROGRAM_ID,
  LENDING_PROGRAM_ID,
  parseLendingMarket,
  RESERVE_SIZE,
} from "@solana/spl-token-lending";
import {
  AccountLayout,
  createApproveInstruction,
  getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount,
  getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint,
  MintLayout,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

async function second(
  sourceLiquidityPubkey: PublicKey,
  lendingMarketPubkey: PublicKey,
  liquidityAmount: number,
  reserveConfig: any,
  pythProductPubkey: PublicKey,
  pythPricePubkey: PublicKey,
  payer: Keypair
) {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

  const sourceLiquidityAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
    sourceLiquidityPubkey
  );

  const lendingMarketAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
    lendingMarketPubkey
  );

  if (sourceLiquidityAccountInfo === null) {
    throw "Error: cannot find the source liquidity account";
  }

  if (lendingMarketAccountInfo === null) {
    throw "Error: cannot find the lending market account";
  }

  const sourceLiquidityAccountData = AccountLayout.decode(
    Buffer.from(sourceLiquidityAccountInfo.data)
  );

  const reserveLiquidityMintPubkey = new PublicKey(
    sourceLiquidityAccountData.mint
  );

  const lendingMarketParsed = parseLendingMarket(
    lendingMarketPubkey,
    lendingMarketAccountInfo
  );

  const reserveKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const reserveLiquiditySupplyKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const reserveCollateralMintKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const reserveCollateralSupplyKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const destinationCollateralKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const userTransferAuthorityKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const [lendingMarketDerivedAuthorityPubkey, _bumpSeed] =
    await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [lendingMarketPubkey.toBytes()],
      LENDING_PROGRAM_ID
    );

  const newReserveParams = {
    liquidityAmount,
    reserveConfig,
    sourceLiquidityPubkey: sourceLiquidityPubkey,
    destinationCollateralPubkey: destinationCollateralKeypair.publicKey,
    reservePubkey: reserveKeypair.publicKey,
    reserveLiquidityMintPubkey: reserveLiquidityMintPubkey,
    reserveLiquiditySupplyPubkey: reserveLiquiditySupplyKeypair.publicKey,
    reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverPubkey:
      reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverKeypair.publicKey,
    reserveCollateralMintPubkey: reserveCollateralMintKeypair.publicKey,
    reserveCollateralSupplyPubkey: reserveCollateralSupplyKeypair.publicKey,
    pythProductPubkey: pythProductPubkey,
    pythPricePubkey: pythPricePubkey,
    lendingMarketPubkey,
    lendingMarketDerivedAuthorityPubkey,
    lendingMarketOwnerPubkey: lendingMarketParsed!.info.owner,
    userTransferAuthorityPubkey: userTransferAuthorityKeypair.publicKey,
  };

  //calculate reserve init balance needed
  //it should include fees for creating all accounts

  const reserveInitBalanceNeeded =
    await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(RESERVE_SIZE);

  const tokenAccountInitBalanceNeeded =
    await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount(connection);

  const mintAccountInitBalanceNeeded = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(
    connection
  );

  //transactions for creating all accounts
  const init_reserve_accounts_transaction_1 = new Transaction();

  init_reserve_accounts_transaction_1
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: reserveKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: reserveInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: RESERVE_SIZE,
        programId: LENDING_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    )
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: reserveCollateralMintKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: mintAccountInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: MintLayout.span,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    )
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: reserveCollateralSupplyKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: tokenAccountInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: AccountLayout.span,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    )
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: destinationCollateralKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: tokenAccountInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: AccountLayout.span,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    );

  const init_reserve_accounts_transaction_2 = new Transaction();

  init_reserve_accounts_transaction_2
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: reserveLiquiditySupplyKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: tokenAccountInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: AccountLayout.span,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    )
    .add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverKeypair.publicKey,
        lamports: tokenAccountInitBalanceNeeded,
        space: AccountLayout.span,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
    );

  //initReserve transaction

  const newReserveTransaction = new Transaction();
  newReserveTransaction
    .add(
      createApproveInstruction(
        newReserveParams.sourceLiquidityPubkey,
        newReserveParams.userTransferAuthorityPubkey,
        payer.publicKey,
        newReserveParams.liquidityAmount
      )
    )
    .add(
      initReserveInstruction(
        liquidityAmount,
        reserveConfig,
        sourceLiquidityPubkey,
        destinationCollateralKeypair.publicKey,
        reserveKeypair.publicKey,
        reserveLiquidityMintPubkey,
        reserveLiquiditySupplyKeypair.publicKey,
        reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverKeypair.publicKey,
        pythProductPubkey,
        pythPricePubkey,
        reserveCollateralMintKeypair.publicKey,
        reserveCollateralSupplyKeypair.publicKey,
        lendingMarketPubkey,
        lendingMarketDerivedAuthorityPubkey,
        lendingMarketParsed!.info.owner,
        userTransferAuthorityKeypair.publicKey
      )
    );

  try {
    const one = await connection.sendTransaction(
      init_reserve_accounts_transaction_1,
      [
        payer,
        reserveKeypair,
        reserveCollateralMintKeypair,
        reserveCollateralSupplyKeypair,
        destinationCollateralKeypair,
      ]
    );

    await connection.confirmTransaction(one);

    const two = await connection.sendTransaction(
      init_reserve_accounts_transaction_2,
      [payer, reserveLiquiditySupplyKeypair, reserveLiquidityFeeReceiverKeypair]
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(two);

    const three = await connection.sendTransaction(newReserveTransaction, [
      payer,
      userTransferAuthorityKeypair,
    ]);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(three);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return reserveKeypair.publicKey;
}

// console.log(LENDING_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58());

second(
  new PublicKey("812JkhJqsYSawohAvN1UZvBGoBE2N3jwiVrayJrc2Lew"),
  new PublicKey("BuShkMwKPFo6eBmbL46tPqzPUaSms1dgEjUavHFDo3fQ"),
  1,
  {
    optimalUtilizationRate: 60,
    loanToValueRatio: 1,
    liquidationBonus: 10,
    liquidationThreshold: 5,
    minBorrowRate: 2,
    optimalBorrowRate: 4,
    maxBorrowRate: 10,
    fees: {
      borrow_fee_wad: 1,
      flash_loan_fee_wad: 3,
      host_fee_percentage: 1,
    },
  },
  new PublicKey("6NpdXrQEpmDZ3jZKmM2rhdmkd3H6QAk23j2x8bkXcHKA"),
  new PublicKey("5SSkXsEKQepHHAewytPVwdej4epN1nxgLVM84L4KXgy7"),
  GET_PAYER
);
```

and I get error after calling the second instruction
and the error is

```
  at async second (/home/vimal/blockchain/token-lending/scripts/second.ts:237:19) {
  logs: [
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Approve',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2928 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 6TvznH3B2e3p2mbhufNBpgSrLx6UkgvxtVQvopEZ2kuH invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Init Reserve',
    'Program log: Error: InvalidArgument',
    'Program 6TvznH3B2e3p2mbhufNBpgSrLx6UkgvxtVQvopEZ2kuH consumed 5789 of 397072 compute units',
    'Program 6TvznH3B2e3p2mbhufNBpgSrLx6UkgvxtVQvopEZ2kuH failed: invalid program argument'
  ]
}
```

Comment: This question needs more detail. I asked you on Discord to please include the code you're using.

Comment: i have updated it please review it